# Exception Specification

Tags: java, exception

Does Exception specification is a part of method signature? 
What I mean is:

```
public void someMethod(String myString) throws IOException
```

is '*throws IOException*'     a part of a signature of this method?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787644/exception-specification/2787667#2787667) and in response to the comment

> @ Jon Skeet Why then I cant have public void run() throws IOException in a class which implements Runnable? – Knowing me knowing you

Section 8.4.6 of the Java Language Specification (3rd ed) says:

> A method that overrides or hides another method (Section 8.4.8), including methods that implement `abstract` methods defined in interfaces, may not be declared to throw more checked exceptions than the overridden or hidden method.
>
> More precisely, suppose that *B* is a class or interface, and *A* is a superclass or superinterface of *B*, and a method declaration *n* in *B* overrides or hides a method declaration *m* in *A*.  If *n* has a `throws` clause that mentions any checked exception types, then *m* must have a `throws` clause, and for every checked exception type listed in the `throws` clause of *n*, that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasure of the `throws` clause of *m*; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

It's not a matter of method signature here, but a matter of not requiring callers to account for exceptions that aren't required to be checked by the 'original' method they are calling.

Answer (score 5):

No. From [section 8.4.2 of the Java Language Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.2):

> Two methods have the same signature if
>   they have the same name and argument
>   types.
>
> Two method or constructor declarations
>   M and N have the same argument types
>   if all of the following conditions
>   hold:
>
> They have the same number of formal
>   parameters (possibly zero) They have
>   the same number of type parameters
>   (possibly zero) Let  be the
>   formal type parameters of M and let
>    be the formal type
>   parameters of N. After renaming each
>   occurrence of a Bi in N's type to Ai
>   the bounds of corresponding type
>   variables and the argument types of M
>   and N are the same.

So two methods with the same name and arguments but different declared exceptions, they have the same signature.

Furthermore, from [the document Bozho quotes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> Definition: Two of the components of a
>   method declaration comprise the *method
>   signature*—the method's name and the
>   parameter types.

No mention of exceptions there...

EDIT: As for overriding a method (or implementing an interface), from [section 8.4.8.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8.3):

> A method declaration must not have a
>   throws clause that conflicts (§8.4.6)
>   with that of any method that it
>   overrides or hides; otherwise, a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet Why then I cant have public void run() throws IOException in a class which implements Runnable?

Comment: Jon is right :)

But perhaps something for the author to take note of. You can declare that your methods throws an exception that lower in the exception heirachy than the the exception declared in the interface / super class method and it will still be a valid implementation / override of the method.

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: Because implementing an interface or overriding a method has to do more than just match the signature. It also has to avoid declaring that it will throw any more checked exceptions than those declared.

Comment: Ah the exception forms part of the contract, the interface Runnable required you implement void run() throwing an exception would violate this contract. If the contract was void run() throws Exception; then your implementation would be ok.